# Read Sharepoint list into object

Tags: 2010, csom, .net, serialization

I need to compare an xml document with the records in a SharePoint list in a vb.Net client side application. Using Visual Studio 2015.
My plan was to read all list items in an object. I am fine until I read the list into an XElement object, but cannot really go further. I wanted to deserialize it, but running into issues.
The parsed XML looks like (I removed lots of attributes):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rs:data ItemCount="3" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset">
    <z:row ows_Title="Customer1" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
    <z:row ows_Title="Customer2" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
    <z:row ows_Title="Customer3" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
</rs:data>
```

And when I try to serialize this, I get the error message:

```
Message=<data xmlns='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'> was not expected.
```

I tried to deserialize every single row, but then another, similar message appeared:

```
Message=<row xmlns='#RowsetSchema'> was not expected.
```

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
result = lists.GetListItems(strListID, strViewID, query, viewFields, 2000, queryOptions, Nothing)

Dim customerslist As XElement = XElement.Parse(result.ToString)
Dim customers As XElement = XElement.Parse(customerslist.Nodes(0).ToString)
Dim kwcusts As New kwCustomers
For i As Integer = 0 To customers.Nodes.Count
    Dim customer As XElement = XElement.Parse(customers.Nodes(i).ToString)
    Dim kwcust As New kwCustomer
    Dim reader As IO.StringReader = New IO.StringReader(customer.ToString)
    Dim xRoot As New Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute
    xRoot.Namespace = "#RowsetSchema"
    Dim xmlserializer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(kwcust.GetType, xRoot)
    kwcust = xmlserializer.Deserialize(reader)
    kwcusts.customers.Add(kwcust)
Next
```

Probably I am missing something trivial, so in anyone sees it, please give me a hint. Thanks.

I did further research on this. I noticed that the .ToString method does not add XML declaration to the string, so I need to add it myself. Still this does not solve the issue with the namespaces and prefixes that I don't know how to handle with deserialization.